# Use input() as an argument in a function in Python

Tags: python, function, input

I created this function that returns the GDP per capita and military spending per capita for some countries I am analyzing based on a particular year.

```
def compare(year):
    simple = data.loc[year, :].sort_values(by = "gdp_pc", ascending = False)
    simple = simple.reset_index()
    simple = simple.drop(["gdp_share", "military_exp", "pop", "gdp"], axis = 1)
    simple = simple.round(2)
    simple.columns = ["Countries", "GDP per capita", "Military spending per capita"]
    simple.index = simple.index + 1

    return simple
```

I have already tested the function and it works fine. However, I would like to make it more user-friendly and have the user input the year (argument of the function). How do I do this?

Comment: How are you calling the `compare` function?

Comment: `compare(2010)`

Comment: For the record, making a function take input via `input` from the user directly is not making it more friendly. It's making it *less* reusable. 99% of functions can and should receive input as arguments and `return` values. The other 1% are functions that do nothing but accept user input and provide output, with all use of the input and production of the output values handled by calling other normal functions in between. Usually, the other functions logically fit into the `main` method of your program (they may be factored out for cleanliness, but they're logically part of `main`).

Comment: Totally agree, @ShadowRanger. But this is for a project for school and one of the requirements is to use `input` from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a wrapper function; let `compare` do its thing (the actual comparison), and let another function take care of calling `input` and passing the response to `compare`.

```
def do_comparison():
    year = int(input("Enter a year to compare against: "))
    return compare(year)
```